# Aws Marketplace ResolveCustomer action fails with com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException when called

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-marketplace, aws-rest-api

I have been trying to do the Aws resolve customer via API, But I get Unknown operation exception.

Service NAme is: aws-amrketplace

Below is the screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoLHb.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Service NAme is: aws-amrketplace

try changing "aws-amrketplace" tp "aws-marketplace"

Comment: Oh, the irony! You point out a typo error in the question by including a typo error in your answer! I was thinking of editing it, but now I'm not inclined tp. ‎

Comment: Now I can't edit it either in order tp maintain the integrity of your comment. Let it be a reminder tp us all tp proofread our comments in a forum where the average user has an above average sense of critical analysis!